# UnityUploadFailed: There was an error uploading the Android App Bundle. Try again later or contact Google Play developer support if the error persists

Tags: unity-game-engine, file-upload, google-play

There was an error uploading the Android App Bundle. Try again later or contact Google Play developer support if the error persists
I am getting this error and I tried resolving it using multiple things like clearing cookies, using different browser, using different internet connection. Nothing Worked.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That can happen if the app bundle you're trying to upload has the same version code as an app bundle that has been already uploaded. Double check to see that it has a higher version code.